# How to Properly Implement a Custom Loading Screen in Java

Tags: java, swing, loading, splash-screen

I am trying to make a custom loading screen in Java (not using the `JProgressBar`). Right now I have just tried making a loading bar that slowly fills the screen left to right with a black rectangle. To test this, I made a simple program that factors random numbers. I run the factoring code on a separate thread and I have the graphics get the progress of the factoring once every 100 milliseconds. However, sometimes the application becomes not responsive for like 10 seconds, then continues to run. **How can I properly implement a custom loading screen in Java or what is wrong with the code I am using now?**

Here is the code:

```
public class Factorer implements Runnable, Loadable {

    private static Random r = new Random();

    private volatile int numOn;

    private volatile int numsTotal;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Factorer fact = new Factorer(25);

        LoadingFrame f = new LoadingFrame(fact);
        fact.run();

    }

    public Factorer(int nNums){

        numsTotal = nNums;

    }

    public void factorRandomNumber(){

        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        int n = randomNumber;

        List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {

            while (n % i == 0) {

                factors.add(i);
                n /= i;

            }

        }

    }

    public void factorRandomNumbers(){

        for(numOn = 0; numOn < numsTotal; numOn++){

            factorRandomNumber();

        }

    }

    public float getProgress(){

        return ((float) numOn) / ((float) numsTotal);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        factorRandomNumbers();

    }

}
```

Here is the loadable interface:

```
public interface Loadable {

    public float getProgress();

}
```

Here is the graphics class:

```
public class LoadingFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8290713730328501888L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    private Loadable loadable;

    public LoadingFrame(Loadable l){

        super("Loading Test");

        this.loadable = l;

        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                repaint();

            }

        });

        t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, (int) (loadable.getProgress() * (float) WIDTH), HEIGHT);

    }

}
```

Comment: Look at [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) & note that for speed, it is entirely AWT based. See also [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) in the tutorial.

Comment: @AndrewThompson will that work if I want to show the loading screen after the program has already started up and everything?

Comment: AFAIU yes, but I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

> I run the factoring code on a separate thread

Well, yes and no. Your `Factorer` class implements runnable, but you never treat the class as a separate Thread.

Instead you just use:

```
fact.run();
```

If you are trying to use this class as a reusable separate Thread then somewhere in your code you would have:

```
new Thread( new Factorer() ).start();
```

to actually start the Thread.

However, because the JVM starts in a separate Thread from the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` you code is running on a separate Thread but more by chance than design.

Also the logic in your `Factorer` class won't work because when you invoke the getProgress() method you will always get the same value returned. That is the `factoroRandomNumbers()` number is executed once at the start of the programs and the `numOn` and `numsTotal` will then be initialized to their final values.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
```

You should NOT be overriding paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` on a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame.

Your Timer logic is incorrect. All you do is invoke repaint(), but as I stated earlier the returned value will never change. What you really need to do is invoke a method like getNextValue(). This method would get a value from your `List` containing the random numbers.

To better understand how Swing works you need to read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You may want to start with section on:

1. Concurrency in Swing
2. Performing Custom Painting

It would probably be easier to use a `SwingWorker` (as discussed in the Concurrency in Swing section). This will create a separate Thread for you. Then you have looping code that generates a random value and "publishes" this value. When this value is published you then repaint the frame with the value.